# Read only textbox in Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm working on a project using lightswitch, and I need to make the textbox control read only when the field has a value. I tried using the ControlAvailable event and it works but when I try to cast the object it throws a CastException because the object passed as a parameter is actually a Textblock, I don't know why it happens since I've chosen the textbox control. Here is my code:

`this.FindControl("Segurado_Altura").ControlAvailable += Altura_ControlAvailable;

```
    void Altura_ControlAvailable(object sender, ControlAvailableEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtAltura = e.Control as TextBox;

        if (txtAltura != null)
        {
            if (this.Segurado.Altura.HasValue)
            {
                txtAltura.IsReadOnly = true;
            } 
        }
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I've never had much joy with IsReadOnly. I have used this to an extent in the past:

this.FindControl("YourTextBox").IsEnabled = true;

HTH.